# runs scoring prior to a forced 3rd out being made

Tags: softball

I have played this game for 40 years, however, yesterday I experienced a "first."  Runner is at third, two out ...batter hits but is super slow running.  The play for the out develops terribly slowly and the runner at third crosses home.  Much later, the throw gets to first, forcing the third out.  Does the run count.  I thought not, but in the confusion - I'm second guessing...

Comment: Exactly which rules are you using? If you're using a derivative of the baseball/MLB rules, this is [covered in this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/does-a-run-count-if-its-made-on-the-same-play-as-the-3rd-out).

Comment: No (commonly used) rules of softball/baseball vary on this particular topic, so I think that's a fine duplicate to use.  Anthony, if you happen to have the specific ruleset you use at hand, we can always add that to the linked question (which was *not* MLB specific).