# Does an out made after a failure to tag up count as a force out?

Tags: rules, baseball

Consider the following play:

- There are runners on 2nd and 3rd with one out.
- The batter hits a line out to center for the second out.
- The runner on 3rd tags up correctly and crosses home plate.
- The runner on 2nd fails to tag and breaks for 3rd on contact.
- The throw goes home and the catcher immediately throws to 2nd for the third out.

Does the run count, or is this a [force out negating the run](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/does-a-run-count-if-its-made-on-the-same-play-as-the-3rd-out)?

Answer (score 2):

The [following rules](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf) are relevant here:

How a Run Scores, Rule 5.08:

> 5.08 How a Team Scores
>
> > (a) One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and touches first, second, third and home base before three men are put out to end the inning.
> > EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner ad- vances to home base during a play in which the third out is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first base; (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by a pre- ceding runner who is declared out because he failed to touch one of the bases.

Rule 5.09(b)(6), which defines "forced out":

> He or the next base is tagged before he touches the next base, after he has been forced to advance by reason of the batter becoming a runner. However, if a following run- ner is put out on a force play, the force is removed and the runner must be tagged to be put out. The force is re- moved as soon as the runner touches the base to which he is forced to advance, and if he overslides or overruns the base, the runner must be tagged to be put out. However, if the forced runner, after touching the next base, retreats for any reason towards the base he had last occupied, the force play is reinstated, and he can again be put out if the defense tags the base to which he is forced;

In the example given, the run scored *before* three were out, and the third out was not scored on a force play.  As such, the run counts.

I assume the question here is, "is failing to tag up a force play"; the answer is no.  While the runner is put out in a similar manner (by tagging the bag), it is not considered a force play.

Comment: So in sense it becomes an appeal rather than a force out.

Comment: _Literally_ an appeal play. 5.09(c): "Appeal plays: Any runner shall be called out, on appeal, when: (1) After a fly ball is caught, he fails to retouch his original base before he or his original base is tagged"

Comment: @PhilipKendall I believe technically an appeal is only when it’s after the play is completed (and they do the appeal process where they step off and throw to the bag ).

Answer (score 1):

Tag ups are not force outs.  They're called timing plays.  Any runs scored before an out is made for not tagging up count.

Rule 8-2-6 section 8

Answer (score 0):

> However, if the forced runner, after touching the next base, retreats **for any reason** towards the base he had last occupied, the force play is reinstated, and he can again be put out if the defense tags the base to which he is forced.

And there it is... yes, it is a definitely a force-play. Anytime a player is *forced* to go to a bag, the force is on, and therefore, no tag has to be made.

I just saw this happen in a game, and my first thought was that the run should count because it happened first, but when the umpires ruled otherwise because the force was on, I realized that I was wrong. Luckily, we had umpires who knew their stuff!

Comment: You are quoting from the later part of 5.09(b)(6), which only applies during a force play.  But with no runner on first, this was never a force play.  A force can't be reinstated if it wasn't there in the first place.